# Treatment of 2-Nitrophenol

Tags: organic-chemistry

What are the ways to treat / disassemble 2-Nitrophenol ?

Is there an academic article explaining and detailing the process?

Answer (score 2):

I hope when you ask what are the ways to treat/disassemble 2-nitrophenol, you are asking how to purify industrial waste water from nitrophenol pollutants. If so, there are few research have done in the field. It is well known that nitrophenols are some of the most refractory pollutants present in industrial waste waters. Because of their high stability and solubility in water, the degradation of these compounds to non-dangerous levels has been a very difficult process. One promising method of purification is the photocatalytic degradation of organic and inorganic pollutants in aqueous dispersions. Accordingly, the photolysis of nitrophenols in a homogeneous medium irradiated by UV light has been reported in several occasions. One such research used the photocatalytic degradation of 2-, 3-, and 4-nitrophenol in aqueous titania (anatase; a mineral form of titanium dioxide, $\ce{TiO2}$) dispersions irradiated by near-UV light (Ref.1), the abstract of which states that:

> The results are reported of an investigation into the photodegradation of nitrophenol isomers carried out in aqueous titania (anatase) dispersions under various experimental conditions. We investigated the influence of various parameters on the photodegradation rate, such as the concentrations of the catalyst, dissolved oxygen and organic compound, and the presence of various anions in the dispersion. A plausible explanation is proposed for the influence of these parameters, both mechanistic and kinetic factors being accounted for. Gas chromatography and mass spectrometry were used as analytical methods in order to determine intermediate products. Spectroscopic methods (UV-vis and IR) were used to obtain information on the fate of adsorbed and intermediate species formed during the reaction.

The research found out that 2- and 4-nitrophenols were photooxidized with similar photodegradation rates (2-nitrophenol been slightly faster) and with faster rates than that of 3-nitrophenol. A mixture of nitrites and nitrates has been found at the end of these photodegradation runs.

Palmisano and others have also studied the effects of these rate with $\ce{pH}$ (Ref.2) and an increase of the substrate concentration.

**References:**

1. V. Augugliaro, L. Palmisano, M. Schiavello, A. Sclafani, L. Marchese, G. Martra, F. Miano, “Photocatalytic degradation of nitrophenols in aqueous titanium dioxide dispersion,” *Applied Catalysis* **1991**, *69(1)*, 323–340 (https://doi.org/10.1016/S0166-9834(00)83310-2).
2. V. Augugliaro, M. J. López-Muñoz, L. Palmisano, J. Soria, “Influence of $\ce{pH}$ on the degradation kinetics of nitrophenol isomers in a heterogeneous photocatalytic system,” *Applied Catalysis A: General* **1993**, *101(1)*, 1991, 7–13 (https://doi.org/10.1016/0926-860X(93)80133-B).